# One transaction per User object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I `save` a `User` all current dirty `Users` are commited. What do I have to change that a `save` only commits the transaction for that specific `User`?

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
})

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', function() {
    this.resource('user', { path: ':user_id' })
  })
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.find();
  }
});

App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  startEditing: function() {
    this.transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
    this.transaction.add(this.get('content'));
  },

  save: function( user ) {
    user.transaction.commit();
  }  
})

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  lastName: DS.attr('string')
})

App.User.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  lastName: "Clinton"
}, {
  id: 2,
  lastName: "Obama"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `startEditing` is never called, otherwise this would probably be ok.

The other option is that you save multiple times the record. Once a record is saved, it is moved back to the store's default transaction. Any subsequential call to `save` would actually commit the store's transaction.